# unique var per .click( function() {..} );

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like each click is associated with the right occurrence in the table `boxes`.

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();

const   bNumber = 2;
var boxes   = new Array(bNumber);

boxes[0]    = new Array("#cch", "#cc");
boxes[1]    = new Array("#sinh", "#sin");

for(var k=0;k<bNumber;k++) {
 J( boxes[k][0] ).click( function() {           
  //J( boxes[k][1] ).toggle();
 });
}
```

With this solution, each click is associated with `boxes[2][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has no block scope, only function scope. That is why creating functions in a loop is tricky. Every closure has a reference to the same variable (`k` in your case). After the last iteration of the loop, `k` has the value `2`.

To capture the current value of the loop counter you have to introduce a new scope, i.e. call a function. E.g. with an *immediate function*:

```
for(var k=0;k<bNumber;k++) {
    (function(index) {
        J( boxes[index][0] ).click( function() {           
            J( boxes[index][1] ).toggle();
        });
    }(k));
}
```

Another way is to create a function that generates the click handler:

```
function getClickHandler(element) {
    return function() {element.toggle()});
}

for(var k=0;k<bNumber;k++) {
    J(boxes[k][0] ).click(getClickHandler(J(boxes[k][1])));
}
```

---

**OT**:

You should not use  `new Array` to initialize arrays. There is no need to define the size of the array beforehand. Using array literal notation is more concise:

```
var boxes = [["#cch", "#cc"], ["#sinh", "#sin"]];
```

Comment: scoping is **not** a problem in this instance. See http://jsfiddle.net/mTK8S/ There is no access to `k` from within a *function context*, so closures and lexical scope are not important here.

Comment: @jAndy: It is. In your fiddle you are not accessing `k` in the click handler. But the OP does. See http://jsfiddle.net/mTK8S/1/

Comment: @jAndy: Then what do think does the commented line `//J( boxes[k][1] ).toggle();` do?

Comment: @jAndy: Well, I assume he commented it out because it didn't work... or what do you mean? Note the last sentence: *With this solution, each click is associated with **boxes[2][1]***

Comment: @Felix: Well looks like it. I didn't say anything then. Yes, I didn't realize the commented line is actually the problem BECAUSE it's commented.

Comment: @Felix @jAndy Thanks for your help. Yes, the commented line, is the problem. And it is solved with the new scope function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();

const   bNumber = 2;
var boxes   = new Array(bNumber);

boxes[0]    = new Array("#cch", "#cc");
boxes[1]    = new Array("#sinh", "#sin");

function toggleHandler(k) {
  J( boxes[k][1] ).toggle();
}

for(var k=0;k<bNumber;k++) {
 J( boxes[k][0] ).click( function() {           
  toggleHandler(k);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For readable and understandable code, store the target box on the element as 'data'?

```
for(var k=0;k<bNumber;k++) {
 J(boxes[k][0]).data("box") = $(boxes[k][1]);
 J(boxes[k][0]).click( function() {           
  J(this).data("box").toggle();
 });
}
```